# Accessing Web Methods service via .NET - Access Denied

Tags: c#, .net, webmethod, access-denied

We have 2 web methods servers, one that is accessible via our internal network and one that is accessible outside of our network.  The WSDLs are both accessible so I know the services are up and running correctly.

The following .NET code will work when ran on our external server (so it is accessing the external web methods server).

```
public WebMethodsService()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
   binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

    var ea = new
            EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebMethodsServer"]);

    _client = new vendorSelfService_PortTypeClient(binding, ea);

    if (_client.ClientCredentials != null)
    {
        _client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebMethodsUserName"];
        _client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebMethodsPassword"];
    }

    _timeout = int.MaxValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    _port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebMethodsInvokeUriPort"];
    _url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebMethodsInvokeUri"];
}

public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    var find = new ValidateUser
    {
        userName = userName,
        password = password
    };

    fault17 foundFault;
    transportInfo17 transportInfo;
    var response = _client.ISearch_ValidateUser(find, null, _timeout, _port, _url, null, out foundFault, out transportInfo);
    ProcessWebMethodsResponse(response, foundFault, transportInfo);

    return response.ValidateUserResult;
}

public void ProcessWebMethodsResponse(object results, object fault, object info)
{
    if (fault != null)
    {
        var correctFault = new fault();
        WebMethodsMapper.MapProperties(fault, correctFault);

        var correctTransport = new transportInfo();
        WebMethodsMapper.MapProperties(info, correctTransport);

        var anyFaults = correctFault.ToFaultString(correctTransport);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(anyFaults))
        {
            throw new WebException(anyFaults);
        }
    }

    if (results == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidDataException("Cannot find results...");
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to run the code through Visual Studio's IDE on my local machine.  I consistently receive the following error:

[image]

[My research](http://forums.asp.net/t/1112505.aspx) indicates that there's a problem with using .NET and Web Methods.  .NET doesn't negotiate the authentication the way Web Methods expects it.

If it helps, the WSDL is only accessible within Internet Explorer's browser if I add an exception to the proxy.  I do not know where I would do that in this code...I'm assuming .NET will pick up my proxy exceptions, especially if I'm not telling it to use a proxy at all in the web.config file.

As always, any help is appreciated!  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What is the underlying 500 error? Anything in the event logs. I would expect authentication issues to give a 4** error, not 500.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in the event logs on my computer where I'm running Visual Studio.  The Web Methods guru is out today, but yesterday he said he wasn't event seeing any validation/authorization requests to that server.

Comment: As far as I know, using Basic Authentication, .NET sends the initial request without credentials, and upon receiving a HTTP 401 response, it repeats the request including credentials. This is correct behavior but some servers don't support this. I agree with ChrisBint, HTTP 500 means something is wrong on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permissions issue. Your web service has `read` permissions probably set to `Anonymous`, which means anyone can see its WSDL, but its `execute` permission is set to something else. To confirm this, set the `execute` permission to `Anonymous`, and retry.

Then it's a matter of how you want to pass credentials through; perhaps start by creating an IS user, add it to a group and set that group to the web service's execute permission; then hard-code that user's username and password into your code.

Once that's working and you're happy, I'd suggest setting up single sign-on (e.g. SAML?) for a real system if it needs authentication/authorisation.